# How to compare two timestamps with erlang?

Tags: erlang, timestamp

Need help to compare 2 timestamps, e.g.: `"2016-02-23 02:41:56"`, `"2015-03-23 09:33:25"`
and get the smaller one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
> min("2016-02-23 02:41:56", "2015-03-23 09:33:25").      
"2015-03-23 09:33:25"
```

It's a nice property of time in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format that they could be compared lexicographically.

Comment: great! ty for your help Hynek